# What type of scheduling algorithm should I use?

Tags: java, scheduling, scheduler

I am writing a program that takes a number of tasks written in Java that are then executed on machines on the same LAN (the details of how that happens is not in this question scope).

The tasks will all be given at once to the program meaning the main part of the work is splitting the tasks up and assigning tasks to machines on the network. I am presuming this will be done with some kind of scheduling algorithm.

E.g. The program gets 50 tasks, it has 3 computers on the LAN each have 4 cores. How should the tasks be scheduled? Could it be done by splitting the tasks with the number of machines factoring in the number of cores the machine has?

Assuming I have the hardware specification of these machines, what algorithm should I use to schedule these tasks?

Comment: What other requirements do you have?  Is there some reason not to just use first-come-first-served?

Comment: There are some details missing. E.g. hardware specifications are totally useless, unless you can determine the approx. number of operations needed/ space required ect.. Also you'd need to know how long it takes for the machines to communicate in relation to the time it takes to execute the tasks.

Comment: @azurefrog I have updated the question - I considered using the FCFS algorithm however the time to execute could vary between tasks meaning if I send a group of tasks containing a large task to a machine with low resources it would take forever to complete. However this project is in the early stages of development so wanted to understand what was out there more than anyting.

Comment: @fabian The project is in the early stages of development so I have removed the complexity of machine communication (in terms of task execution). This is mainly to find out what kind of algorithms there are out there that would fit this spec. The hardware details will inform the program how much resource each machine has that can be factored into how many tasks can be executed on the machine

Comment: Most scheduling algorithms I've seen have been pretty simple.  The user assigns a class to a task, and the tasks are sent to computers depending on the priority of the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I worked out that my problem is more of a load balancing issue rather than a scheduling issue. The tasks need to be correctly balanced between the available network resources weighted by the number of cores on each machine.